# Laravel - How Convert Thousand Comma to Decimal Number

Tags: php, laravel, format, currency, number-formatting

i have input form currency with format like this 1,000.00

and i want to save in database in decimal format like 1000.00

how to change it in controller, when save it it will automatically change to decimal format?

```html
$num = '3,500.20';
$formattedNum = number_format($num,  3, '', '');
echo $formattedNum;
```

the code above convert to 3000 not 3500.20

Comment: have you tried `$result = str_replace(',', '', $num);`?

Comment: Use JavaScript to check the form first and prompt the user for correct input format. That way you don't mess with the users input. You still need to check again in PHP but it's better to ask the user for a correct format than trying to parse it correct

Comment: replace comma with blank, `str_replace(',', '', $num);` and make your database column as decimal with 2 decimal place. **DECIMAL(10,2)** during migration.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str_replace` of php to get you result:

```
<?php
     $num = '3,500.20';
     $formattedNum = str_replace(',', '', $num);
     echo $formattedNum;
?>
```

`str_replace` funcation replace your ',' with '' a blank value,
To read more about `str_replace` you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove comma with `str_replace(',', '', $num)` for example.

But better to get correct value right from your input.

Input format shouldn't affect actual input value which is 3500.20, that doesn't look as good practice.

Also number_format is not for converting string to numbers, on the contrary it makes pretty string from number(integer/float).

Answer (score 0):

You can try str_replace for the desired result:-

```
$number = '3,500.20';
$number = str_replace(',', '', $number);
echo $number;
```

Output
    3500.20